# How to represent x and y in svg symbol

Tags: html, css, svg

Based on https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/
I have a representation of symbols taken from svg files. The original svgs have properties like x, y, height and width.
When adding the svgs to one svg file and making them symbols, I found that adding x, y height and width attributes to `<symbol>` is not valid svg.

I resolved the issue for height and width, by adding them in the style attribute of the `<symbol>` since that one is supported. My question is, how can I go about adding the x and y attributes to the `<symbol>`?

The final file, is composed of only one `<svg>` and multiple svg `<symbol>`

Example original file:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

File after changing it to symbol:

```
<svg style="display:none;">
<symbol id="circle" width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</symbol> 
</svg>
```

In the above width and height are not valid attributes for symbol.

The symbol is used the following way:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#circle" />
</svg>
```

However, in the above, it doesn't expand to take the width and the height. I also tried nesting an svg inside the symbol like this and it also doesn't respect the height and width:

```
<svg style="display:none;">
    <symbol id="circle">
<svg width="100" height="100">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
       Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
    </symbol> 
    </svg>
```

Comment: Please include an example in your question so we can see better what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<symbol>` element does not have `x`, `y`, `width` or `height` attributes.

Your original file:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

should be converted to:

```
<svg style="display:none;">
   <symbol id="circle">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   </symbol> 
</svg>
```

And then reference it with a `<use>` as follows.  If the original SVG had `width` and `height` values, then they should go in the `<use>`.

```
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="#circle" width="200" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

If you want to position the symbol, use `x` and `y` attributes, or a `transform` on the `<use>`.

```
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="#circle" width="200" height="100" x="300" y="50"/>
</svg>

<svg>
   <use xlink:href="#circle" width="200" height="100" transform="translate(300,50)"/>
</svg>
```

Note that `<symbol>` elements **do** support `viewBox`, so if your original SVG has a `viewBox`, it should be added to the symbol.